# Return System.out to String

Tags: java, sparql, jena, owl, protege

I have query Sparql on OWL 'ressu.owl' file which created with protege 3.x.. am obliged to point to transform the resultset into something usable like JTextArea for this i work with `ResultSetFormatter()`

i use it like this

```
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
```

and it give me this result in console of Netbeans:

[image]

but when i try to return System.out to String ::

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
ByteArrayOutputStream go = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
ResultSetFormatter.out((OutputStream)go ,results, query);
String result = go.toString();
jTextArea1.setText(result);
```

it show me in the JtextArea  only

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| hasnamefonctioncontrainte        | hasnamefonctionprincipale 
===============================================================
```

help
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm sorry.. I really didn't understand this question as all.

Comment: What do you mean by "return X to Y" here?

Comment: Convert X to Y, i have `ResultSetFormatter.out` i must convert it to String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is an iterator.

You printed it out at

```
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
```

so now you are at the end of the iterator and the second call:

```
ResultSetFormatter.out((OutputStream)go ,results, query);
```

iterates from that point (the end) hence no rows.

Try `ResultSetFactory.copyResults` to get a result set you can rewind (or just don't print it out).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should have done it. 
I recommend you to create a PrintStream that wraps a ByteArrayOutputStream, the following way:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
```

Then pass the  print-stream to the call of "out":

```
ResultSetFormatter.out(ps, results, query) ;
```

Then try to create a string from the byte array output stream:

```
String s = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

And perform

```
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: it return this error : `must be caught or declared to be thrown` on `String s = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");` and if i add try/catch the same result returned as i post

Comment: thank you very match your solution is good too i just dont delete this line `ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;` as @AndyS said  (or just don't print it out).